# how to generate crystal Report without Database Only for showing Form Data filled by User In c# form Application

Tags: c#

I wants to create An crystal Report without Using Any Database
I Only wants to show the Text entered by the User. 
see Image Below::[image]

I'm VerY novice In c# Form Application

Comment: You can print form as image and insert that image in crystal report. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx http://dotnetfish.blogspot.com/2009/02/dynamic-image-in-crystal-report-9.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are C#; create required TextObjects in your crystal report in design mode(You can not add it dynamically without crystal license). If there are four values in your WinForm and you want these to be published in Crystal Report; you will need to create four TextObjects. After doing this just type this code in the button click event :

```
/*Initialize the Report Object*/
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
/*Load the designed report*/
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyReport.rpt");

/*initialize required TextObjects*/
/*SYNTAX :
TextObject objectName = (TextObject)cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections["name of report section"].ReportObjects["Name of textobject"];

*/
TextObject txt1 = (TextObject)cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["TextObject1"];


TextObject txt2 = (TextObject)cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["TextObject2"];



/*Pass the text value from WinForm TextBox to Crystal Report TextObject*/
txt1.Text = textbox1.Text;
txt2.Text = textbox2.Text;



/*Create a Form and display the crystal report*/
Form frm = new Form();
frm.Height = 800;
frm.Width = 600;

CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
crystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;


crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

frm.Controls.Add(crystalReportViewer1);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

---

That's all :)
/* HAPPY CODING :) */